# What are some potential causes of idiopathic hypersomnia?

Tags: sleep, sleep-cycles

I have been using Google scholar to try to find information about idiopathic hypersomnia. I am struck by the fact that no papers even attempt to provide a pathology (or possible pathologies). Clearly, idiopathic means the pathology is unknown, or there could be multiple causes. There are also some known diseases that cause hypersomnia. Does anyone know of a study that attempts to identify the potential causes?

I read a literature review, Nathaniel Sowa, Idiopathic Hypersomnia. In it he says, "Current research suggests that it is a disorder of hypoarousal, with
several possible underlying changes in CNS neuronal signaling. However, the exact pathophysiology of the condition is largely unknown." Just looking for possibilities

Comment: Hypersomnia could be caused by an improper diet. I can't find much information on this subject either.